# Binding in a ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, binding, swiftui, fetchrequest

I use a `FetchRequest` to fill the elements. Then I'm using a list and want to display some kind of todo elements where you see which one is checked and which one not. Therefor I created a CheckBoxView.

My problem now is, that I need to pass a binding to the view. But how to do that in the ForEach?
If I have a single binding its easy for me, I just generate a `@State` and it works. How to do it here?

```
List {
    ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { item in
        CheckBoxView(checked: item.checked)
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
struct CheckBoxView: View {
    @Binding var checked: Bool
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your `elements` is state of items array, it can be

```
List {
    ForEach(elements.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        CheckBoxView(checked: $elements[i].checked)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why to use indices?

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    ForEach($elements, id: \.self) { element in
        CheckBoxView(checked: element.checked)
    }
}

//    Sometimes we need to use wrapped value of element For Example:

                ForEach($room.guests, id: \.self) { customer in
                    if let customerType = customer.wrappedValue.customerType {
                        VStack {
                            switch customerType {
                            case .newCustomer:
                                GuestSelectionView(customer: customer, isSelected: true, subtitle: Strings.Checkout.Text.NewGuest.title)
                            case .existingCustomer:
                                GuestSelectionView(customer: customer, isSelected: true, subtitle: Strings.Checkout.Text.ExistingGuest.title)
                            }
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingExistingGuestsList) {
                            CheckoutExistingCustomerView(isPresented: $isPresentingExistingGuestsList, guestChoosed: { newCustomer in
                                customer.wrappedValue = newCustomer
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
```